# show output that get method is deprecated how to solve?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
    Main.module.ts
           
    @NgModule({
    
        declarations:[HomeComponent,MasterComponent,],         
        imports:[
            BrowserModule,
            FormsModule,
            RouterModule.forRoot(MainRoutes)
        ],
        providers:[
            {
                provide:BaseLogger,
                useClass:DBLogger
            },
            {provide:"1",useClass:DBLogger},   
            {provide:"2",useClass:ConsoleLogger},
        ],
        bootstrap:[MasterComponent]
    })
    export class MainModule{ 
    }

    ***customer.component.ts***
     I just injection  but provide value not shown in the constructor of the component
    
    @Component({
        selector: 'cust-app',
        templateUrl: './customer.view.html',
        styleUrls: ['./customer.view.css']
    })
    export class CustomerComponent {
        title: string = 'Customer Application';
        customerModel:Customer = new Customer();
        customerModels:Array<Customer> = new Array<Customer>();
    
        loggerObj: BaseLogger = null;
        constructor(_injector: Injector) {
    
            this.loggerObj = _injector.get("1"); 
           -- Show error get is deprecated  I got an error here I just want to provide value 
            I do not know how 
            to inject 
            this.loggerObj.Log();
        }
    }

  CustomerApp.logger.ts
  ---------------------

export interface ILogger{
    Log():void;
}

export class BaseLogger implements ILogger{
    Log(){

    }
}
export class ConsoleLogger extends BaseLogger{
    Log(){
        console.log('Using Console Logger..');
    }
}
export class DBLogger extends BaseLogger{
    Log(){
        console.log('Using Database Logger');
    }
   
}
export class FileLogger extends BaseLogger{
    Log():any{
        console.log('Using File Logger');
    }
}
```

Error :
You can see below code I am trying to use the injector in the constructor
but I did not get("1")
I am struggling to do in
get method is deprecated so how to get 1 value from providing in the constructor of component.
what I want if the value of providing which is present in providers:[] of the main module I want
this "1"
but nothing happens

Comment: Per https://angular.io/api/core/Injector#get you need to use a type or injection token, not just a bare string. See e.g. https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#using-an-injectiontoken-object.

Comment: instead of get("1") can u know which method is used? Deprecated from v4.0.0 use Type or InjectionToken yes I already see this but I didn't get?

Comment: I've already linked you to the docs that show how to define and use an injection token.

Comment: yes !! but i didnt get apply injector to constructor()

Comment: right now i have added my logger code also ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got my answer Here below I gonna step by step to solve this issue

```
step 1> I apply DBLogger as a type to get() 
Ex:  constructor(_injector: Injector) {

        this.loggerObj = _injector.get<BaseLogger>("1");
        this.loggerObj.Log();
     }
  Note: DBLogger already Present in CustomerApp.logger.ts

step 2: instead of assign "1" or "2" to the parameter I have used one line
      export const DB=new InjectionToken("1");
      
     and Apply this DB to the parameter to get<BaseLogger>(DB)
Example :
  export class CustomerComponent {
    loggerObj: BaseLogger = null;
    constructor(_injector: Injector) {

        this.loggerObj = _injector.get<BaseLogger>(DB);// 
        this.loggerObj.Log();
    }


step 3: also apply to the provide value also
       providers:[
        {
            provide:BaseLogger,
            useClass:DBLogger
        },
        {provide:DB,useClass:DBLogger},  // here I apply DB instead of "1" 
    ],
```